# Automatically grant permissions to INSERT on newly created table

Tags: mysql, privileges

I have an user that has the privileges to CREATE tables, as such:

```
GRANT CREATE ON db.* TO `user1`@'%';
```

Moreover, my user has rights to INSERT into some specific tables, *but must not have the privileges to INSERT on all tables.*

```
GRANT INSERT ON db.table1 TO `user1`@'%';
```

The problem I run into is that while the user has privilege to create a table by running:

```
CREATE db.newtable;
```

It can not actually INSERT into this database until I log in as administrator and grant the privileges:

```
GRANT INSERT ON db.newtable TO `user1`@'%';
```

Meaning that having the privilege to create tables actually has no real interest as I stil need to intervene as an administrator before the user can use it in any meaningful way

Is there a way to automatically grant INSERT privileges to user1 on the tables it creates ?

Bonus point if the privileges can be given to multiple users on tables created by any user.

Comment: You have to explicitly grant the users access to the new tables, I'm afraid. This is a limitation in MySQL's privilege system. If you have v8, then you can use roles to grant the new privileges to multiple users.